# No se ejecutar script de Python con el Programador de tareas

Tags: python, windows

Estoy intentando realizar pruebas de ejecutar scripts de python automaticamente con el programador de tareas de windows pero no lo ejecuta.

tengo el siguiente script sencillo el cual realiza una copia de un archivo excel.

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\maxla\\Desktop\\data.xlsx")
    df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\maxla\\Desktop\\data_copy.xlsx")
```

Lo guardo como **test_program.py** en el escritorio.

Inicializo el programador de tareas y queda como sigue:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][3]][3]

Despues de esperar a la hora de ejecucion queda lo siguiente en el historial

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][4]][4]

Y no realiza la accion del script.

Me podrian ayudar con este inconveniente

Comment: Buen día, las imágenes que pusiste no se ven, en general es mejor siempre poner el texto.

Comment: Primero, enfocandonos en el problema, ¿revisaste que tu script no haya tirado ningún error? ¿Programaste la tarea tal y como lo indica [esta pagina](https://www.jcchouinard.com/python-automation-using-task-scheduler/)?

Comment: Segundo, usar pandas para copiar un archivo, no solo me parece overkill, si no que ocupa mas memoria y tiempo. Considera que pandas parsea el excel, crea datos usando objetos de Python y lo carga en memoria entero, procesos que no nos importan si no haremos ninguna modificación al contenido del archivo. La mejor opción es usar el modulo [shutil](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/shutil.html).

Comment: Hola @DanteS. efectivamente realice la tarea como lo indica la pagina. En cuestion de la funcionalidad del script, todo esta correcto al correrlo desde vscode, consola etc.  Gracias por la retro, solo era un script de prueba de lo que se me ocurrio en el momento. Para despues aplicarlo a la tarea completa que tengo programada

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Entre a varios foros donde explicaban que para programar una tarea de un script de Python en Windows se puede creando un archivo .bat

Este archivo tiene que contener la siguiente estructura:

[Ubicación del ejecutable Python] [Ubicación del script de Python]

Y lo realizaban con el ejecutable que viene por default en anaconda.
Entonces el .bat quedaría de la siguiente manera

C:\Users\nameuser\anaconda3\python.exe C:\ScriptsPython\Prueba.py

y funciona correctamente con cualquier librería que viene básica en Python. Sin embargo, si quiero utilizar librerías como pandas, numpy etc no realizaba la acción de script.

Para esto es necesario activar el ambiente virtual de anaconda donde se encuentran las librerías necesarias. Entonces el .bat quedaría

CD C:\Users\nameuser\anaconda3\condabin
CALL activate.bat
CD C:\Users\nameuser\anaconda3
python.exe C:\ScriptsPython\Prueba.py

y de esta manera se lee correctamente el Script.

Mi duda es que en ningún foro comentan el activar el ambiente virtual de anaconda, simplemente llaman el ejecutable y la dirección del script.

Saludos.

Comment: La respuesta a tu duda es simple: probablemente en esos casos no han creado un entorno virtual, si no que han instalado los paquetes en el entorno global.